# WakefulBrodcastReceiver / Alert does not ring (Wakelock? Process killed?)

Tags: java, android, process, android-wake-lock

I've an app which should be an Alarm clock. If I set the Alert time about 5min oder 30min, it will ring as it should, but if I put it something like 4 hours away, it won't ring, neither if my device is never touched (over night) nor if I use it regularly (at day).

In the main method I've got this `Wackelock`:

```
PowerManager powman = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powman.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK,"MyWakelockTag");
wakeLock.acquire();
```

Then I call my `AlarmReceiver` like this:

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(main.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent alarmPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(main.this, 8932, alarmIntent, 0);
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, AlertDate.getTime(), alarmPendingIntent);
```

And finally my `AlarmReceiver` looks like this:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        main.Alert(context);
    }
}
```

My Manifest is here:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

...

<application

...

    <receiver
        android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

So the very shorts question is: why is `main.Alert(context);` not called after a longer time? Is the process maybe killed by the `Android OS`?

Comment: do you have WAKE_UP permission to manifiest ? and declare AlarmReceiver to manifiest

Comment: yes I have both :) I've added it in my post above

Answer (score 0):

@Pixel_95 What's doing `main.Alert(context);` ?
Anyway, PowerManager will need to be FULL_WAKE_LOCK in constructor(not PARTIAL), or something like that, but when you use WakefullBroadcastReceiver, you will need to call `completeWakefulIntent(intent);` to be able to wake device, and if you do that, you won't need the PowerManager code lines.

Comment: now I have `FULL_WAKE_LOCK` and the `completeWakefulIntent(intent):` but it still doesn't work for more than about 3hours ...